Closest point on a convex hull in log(n)
We are given a convex polygon $C = \{P_1, P_2, \dots, P_n\}$, where the points are ordered either clockwise or counter-clockwise. Additionally, we have a point $P_\text{new} = (x, y)$ that lies outside the convex hull. The goal is to find the point $P_i$ in $C$ that is closest to $P_\text{new}$ in a logarithmic time complexity. ($O(\log n)$.)

We can't use sorting because that would take $O(n \log(n))$ time, and also we can't use binary search because of the shape of a convex hull and we might delete the half that contains the answer.

Why would you want to use sorting if the points are already ordered clockwise?

"can't use sorting because that would take $O(n\log(n))$
time" So what is the time limit on preprocessing? Is it known whether the order is clockwise?

By sorting I meant calculating distances to new point in O(n) and then ordering them based on that in O(n Log(n)), We don't have any preprocessing, we just have the points on convex hull in clockwise order, by that we only know that Pi+1 is in a clockwise position regarding Pi.

I dont think that would work, for example look at this image:
link
do you have a specific algorithm on your mind??

(Pondering that, I think a promising special case is a regular polygon with an odd number of vertices/edges. Try finding a solution here, and generalising.)

(@JohnKemeny: is there an efficient "Ternary" Search for "bimodal" functions? I suggested regular $2n+1$gons assuming distance to external points unimodal there. (There may still be two points of minimal distance - they will be adjacent.))

Essentially identical at MATHEMATICS@SE: Algorithm to find the point in a convex polygon closest to an external point.

A clarification is needed in the problem statement. Does the segment, connecting the point $P_{new}$ and the closest to this point polygon vertex, need to be outside the polygon as well? If yes, then even a simple linear search over all vertices can give you a wrong result.

We'll assume that we need to find a vertex $P_i$ of the convex polygon $C$, closest to the external (to the polygon) point $Q$, provided that the segment $\overline{P_i Q}$ lies outside of the polygon.

Step 1. Find left and right tangent line from the point $Q$ to the polygon $C$. That can be done in $O(log(n))$ time for convex polygons - for example, see here. Two tangent lines correspond to two vertices $(P_{left},P_{right})$ of the polygon $C$. These vertices divide the polygon into two polylines - visible from the point $Q$, and invisible from this point.

Step 2. We need to look for the closest vertex in the visible polyline only. The distance from the vertex $P_k$ to the point $Q$ as a function of index $k \in [left, right]$ is unimodal (has a single minimum) - so we can use Ternary Search to find this minimum. This search takes $O(log(n))$ time as well.


Q.E.D.

Start of an answer:
Given $P_{new}$ outside

a regular $(2n+1)$gon (simple case):
Pick an edge $e$ and its vertices $v_a$ and $v_b$.
If their distances  to $P_{new}$ are equal,
either both are closest to $P_{new}$, or the vertex $v_{oe}$ opposite to $e$ is.
Else the closest vertex is between $v_{oe}$ and the closer of $v_a$ and $v_b$, to be found using binary search.
part of a regular polygon:
Start with a wedge-shaped third of a regular polygon with lots ( $n - 1$) of vertices on the outcircle and one incident to the centre. Now move "the tip vertex" $v_t$ a bit closer to the segment; $P_{new}$ is somewhere between $v_t$ and the centre. For good measure, move every third vertex slightly inward (such that it is just outside the chord through its neighbours).
What makes this case look hard?
Start at one of the vertices moved inward, say, $v_i$, the next counter-clockwise from the one opposite to $v_t$:
both its neighbours will be farther from $P_{new}$. Worse, the ninth in both directions, while local minima of distance too, will be farther than $v_i$, too.


(I mistakenly thought I had an idea for case 2.)
